What are the platforms to monitor for academic job search (Tenure Track/ Long-Term Positions) in the Sciences?
Apart from common websites, like Chronicle of Higher Education or Higher Ed Jobs, what are other platforms where academic positions are posted?
I recently missed out on some opportunities by not being on a list-serv (very niche field-specific group) and also got a few opportunities by being on another similar group's email-list. I'm curious to learn what platforms others are using to keep track of open positions.

I suspect that this is very field or even niche specific, as you have found out.

Your PhD adviser should know. It's very field dependent.

Which country are you interested in?

As some of the other comments already mentioned, many such portals are field-specific. However, I can provide some examples from the field of geoscience that may help you search for similar portals in your own discipline, should it differ.

Academic Job portals: Besides the platforms you manages, some other good allrounder portals are academicpositions.com or Times Higher Education.

International professional / academic organizations: In the geosciences, the biggest organizations are the American Geophysical Union (AGU) amd the European Geosciences Union (EGU), both of which have their own job portals (here and here).

National networks: These are a step down in scale, but can be very useful, especially if you are looking for positions in specific countries. For instance, in Germany there is academics.de, for Norway there is jobnorge.no.

Vacancy pages of universities: That sounds pretty obvious, but when I was looking for a tenure position, I tracked the vacancy pages of a number of well-known universities in my field, for instance the NTNU or TU Delft. Some of them (like ETH Zürich) also allow you to set an email alert for new job postings.


Finally, I strongly recommend to ask around your network of colleagues. Many of them may have their own list of job portals to post their own PhD vacancies, or hunt for new jobs themselves. Your colleagues may not only get you onto some of the more obscure list-servs, but if they hear of a vacancy in your field, they may let you know.
Best of luck with your job hunt!
